# Forwarding ssh key using docker composer-compose

Tags: ssh, docker, ssh-keys, forwarding

In docker `18.09+` we can use the following approach to use a forwarded ssh key when building an image:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:experimental
# example file
FROM node:10.15.3-alpine

RUN apk update && apk add openssh-client git

# use the forwarded ssh key
RUN --mount=type=ssh git clone <repo>
```

Then we would build the image like this:

```
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build --ssh default .
```

I would like to use `docker-compose` to achieve this, but it does not seem to work. There is no `--ssh` flag for the docker-compose command and I can't see anything I can set in the `docker-compose.yml` file to accomplish this.

Answer (score 3):

The most upvoted answer as of writing this is wrong. This works fine:

```bash
$ docker compose build --ssh default
```

```bash
$ docker compose version                               
Docker Compose version v2.5.1
```

This believe this requires your public key is visible to the SSH agent:

```bash
ssh-add -L
```

If not, run `ssh-add -K` or on macOS run `ssh-add --apple-use-keychain`.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I think this is currently not supported, based on comments on this issue: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/6358  -- in fact, googling for "docker-compose BuildKit" gives some links to various tickets all appearing to point to the fact that using BuildKit is not currently supported by docker-compose.

The workaround I would try (as well as mentioned in some of these ticket comments) is to build the images seperately, with a shell script calling "docker build", before running docker-compose.

Comment: In the end I actually ditched this thing and used a oauth key created in github instead `RUN git clone --single-branch --branch $BRANCH https://$OAUTH_TOKEN@<REPO> /src/app` so to build you just add a build-arg `OAUTH_TOKEN` - `docker build --build-arg BRANCH=<BRANCH> --build-arg OAUTH_TOKEN=<TOKEN> .`. Doesn't feel really good using experimental features anyway =)